# my pdf file is not selected at first, only in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have an input file to select pdfs. After I select the pdfs, are open text boxes to give a title to each pdf.

Everything is working properly in google chrome.

In internet explorer I'm having a problem that I am not able to figure out why and how to solve.

**My problem:**

In internet explorer when I select a pdf for the first time, nothing happens, the pdf is not selected.

I need to select other pdf, but cant be the first pdf selected, and when I select other pdf  it works.

And then starts to work always fine, but first time I select a pdf I always have this bug.

**You can see my full example with my issue here**: http://jsfiddle.net/j5yeq/3/ (but to see my issue you need to test in internet explorer)

**My Html:**

```
<div class="galerry">               
    <div class="label" style="margin:0;">
        <span class="field">PDFS:</span>
        <input type="file" name="pdfs[]" class="j_galleryp" multiple="multiple" accept="application/pdf"  />
        <div class="j_gfalsep">Selecione quantos pdfs quiser</div>
        <img src="img/upload.png" class="j_gsendp" alt="Enviar Capa" title="Enviar Capa" style="margin:0 0 10px 10px;" />   
        <div class="label" id="teste"></div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

**My jQuery:**

```
$('.j_gsendp').click(function(){
    $('.j_galleryp').click().change(function(){
         var allFiles = this.files;  
         var numFiles = this.files.length;

        $('.j_gfalsep').animate({width:'500'}, 500, function(){
            $(this).html('You selected<strong>'+ numFiles +'</strong> files.'); 

            for(var i = 0; i<numFiles; i++) {
                var file = allFiles[i],
                    name = file.name;
                $('#test').append('<div class="message">Give a title to pdf <strong>'+name+':</strong></div><span>Title for pdf '+name+':</span><input type="text" name="title[]" value=""/><br><br>');
             } 
            });
              this.val('');
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You jquery code has some errors. I can't find the solution for IE at present but even in chrome and firefox this code uploads pdf twice from second time. I've modified the jquery to work properly.

```
$('.j_gsendp').click(function(){
    $('.j_galleryp').trigger('click');
});

$('.j_galleryp').change(function () {
    update();    
});

function update(){
    var input = $('.j_galleryp')[0];
    var allFiles = input.files;
    var numFiles = input.files.length;
    alert(numFiles);
    $('.j_gfalsep').animate({
        width: '400'
    }, 500, function () {
        $(this).html('You select <strong>' + numFiles + '</strong>files.');
        for (var i = 0; i < numFiles; i++) {
            var file = allFiles[i],
                name = file.name;
            $('#test').append('<span class="field">Title of pdf ' + name + ':</span><input type="text" name="title[]" value="' + name + '"/><br><br>');
        }
    });
}
```

Use this jquery code and don't bind event handlers inside other event handlers. You may end up binding same event multiple times.

**NOTE:** I can't edit the question so I answered this as a solution.

Comment: No need to apologise for posting this as a solution, rather than an edit. Your code  **IS** the solution!

Comment: Thank your very much Akash K. I was with this error for a long time without see how can I could solve it. Your solution works perfectly!

Comment: Glad this worked. Didn't test in IE so was not sure if that was working. :)

Comment: Yes, it is working. It was the first thing that I did :)